# Kubernetes pods in pending state for indfinite time..?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using digital ocean kubernetes cluster service and have deployed 9 nodes in cluster but when i'm trying to deploy kafka zookeeper pods few pods get deployed other remain in pending state. i've tried doing

```
kubectl describe pods podname -n namespace
```

it shows 
[image]

its not getting assigned to any nodes
[image]

Comment: Can you share the logs of the problematic pods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pod in Kubernetes always in pending state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377784/pod-in-kubernetes-always-in-pending-state)

Answer (score 0):

check if your deployment/statefulset might have some node Selectors and/or node/pod affinity that might prevent it from running .

also it would be helpful to see more parts of the pod decribe since it might give more details.

there is a message on your print screen about the PersistentVolume Claims so I would also check the status of the pvc objects to check if they are bound or not.

good luck

Comment: I was using digital ocean kubernetes service and i've a really bad experience with it, Now i have shifted to google cloud kubernetes engine. everything works smooth on gcp.